# Special vector product

Tags: vectors

I am looking for the name and if posible its properties of specific vector product # defined as the vector which components pairwise product of operated vector components:

$ (u#v)_i = u_i * v_i $

Comment: This is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: Then the vector space becomes the ring ($k$-algebra) $k^n$.